# Detect and print key combinations Javascript

Tags: javascript, keydown

I'm currently trying to convert user-provided keyboard combinations into their printable versions (so for example if a user presses shift + a I want to be able to detect it and print the string "shift + a" somewhere so that the user knows which combination he associated with the action.

So far I've been using the provided booleans: ctrlKey, altKey, shiftKey and metaKey, and when they're true I add their printable versions to the final string.

It works... to some extent...

I correctly receive the ctrl flag, but the shift flag is erratic (giving shifts when it should not and not giving shifts when it should, although it works OK for some keys) and the alt flag seems to work only on a few keys and the meta flag does not seem to work at all.
Note that my keyboard works properly, that is, these keys work as intended in normal conditions (the shift key allows me to capitalize, the win key allows me to lock my computer, etc...)
Also note that my keyboard is an azerty.

It behaves the same way on the W3schools example:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_key_shiftkey

Here is an example:

[trying with &, which does not require shift on an azerty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC2UW.png)

[trying with 1, which does require shift on an azerty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkIVY.png)

So I assume there's something I'm misunderstanding in the way to detect key combinations. Thanks to all those who'll be willing to help.

```
function logKey(e) {
    var modifier1;
    var modifier2;
    var modifier3;
    var modifier4;
    var display = "";

    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        modifier1 = "ctrl + ";
    }
    else {
        modifier1 = "";
    }
    if (e.altKey) {
        modifier2 = "alt + ";
    }
    else {
        modifier2 = "";
    }
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        modifier3 = "shift + ";
    }
    else {
        modifier3 = "";
    }      
    if (e.metaKey) {
        modifier4 = "meta + ";
    }
    else {
        modifier4 = "";
    }

    display = modifier1 + modifier2 + modifier3 + modifier4 + e.key

    window.alert(display);
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);
```

Comment: You're probably better off keeping a map of keys that are down (including the modifiers) rather than relying on the event information.

Comment: I have used keyboard events extensively and have never once heard of the booleans being "erratic". However, it's possible that the keyboard you are using is "remapping" `&` to shift+7 (which is what it is on a QWERTY keyboard).

Comment: I definitly see a timing issue here.
If you just press "Ctrl" and like a few ms later you press the "A" key for example, your code will trigger *two* keydown Events. -> this leads to your unexpected behaviour. 
More to think about - what If you press 3 keys at once or more, what if you press only one?? - there`s a lot of things to think about...

Answer (score 0):

As skyline3000 hinted in their comment, you are probably better off independently tracking which keys are pressed and then when you need them, simply look at what you've tracked.

Something like this:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const keysDown = [];

input.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (keysDown.indexOf(e.keyCode) === -1) {
    keysDown.push(e.keyCode);
  }
  
  console.log(keysDown);
});

input.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  const index = keysDown.indexOf(e.keyCode);
  
  if (index !== -1) {
    keysDown.splice(index, 1);
  }
  
  console.log(keysDown, e);
});
```

```html
Focus on input to register keys:
<input />
```

This will let you track them way more precisely and can even track lots of keys down at once.

Then, when you want to show which keys they pressed, you just print out your `keysDown` list.

Comment: The biggest issue with this is that if you Alt+Tab, then your code will never be informed of Alt being released.

Comment: That is true, but that is kind of edge-case for any application anyways. When I'm tracking keys like this, I almost always clear the entire list on `window` blur anyways.

Comment: You can add a blur event listener on the window for when the window loses focus and reset the map, or similarly do it on window focus.

Comment: Sure but it just seems like a massive hack when `altKey` etc. already exist and (should!) work 100% of the time.

Comment: True, but it also involves a lot more code to deal with all modifiers (like the original question has above). With this method, you just have a list of keys that don't really matter what they are that you can just output then. Plus, it isn't like you would ever keybind "alt+tab" to do something in an application anyways.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to characterize this as a hack. These boolean properties were only introduced in the working draft (never published) of the DOM level 3 events specification in 2014. This is the way keyboard interactions always had to be programmed before the browsers caught up.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, so I tried @samanime solution, and there's definitely something weird going on with these booleans. First, the shift flag stays "undefined" (I printed its value on keydown) instead of false or true. Second, even the other flags don't always come up true even though they should, like if I use alt+k, the alt flag stays false. What's weird is that inside the event, it works fine, that is, when the event is printed, it shows when a modifier key is pressed just fine, so there must be this information available somewhere, but not from those 4 booleans it seems.

Answer (score 0):

So...

I went back to the problem today, and realized that the issue is not even limited to these booleans. Even if I ignore the booleans and try to use keycodes to register modifier keys being pressed, that does not work (using @samanime code), at least not on Firefox, because apparently my firefox does not trigger a keydown/keyup (or keypress) event when I press the modifier keys like ctrl or alt. It does trigger normally on other keys like the character keys for example.

It works on Chrome though.

Is there some compatibility problem that I'm not aware of? Or is it my Firefox that has an issue somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution:

```js
let keys = {};
let keysPressed = '';

document.onkeydown = handleKey;
document.onkeyup = handleKey;

function handleKey(e) {
  // Indicate key pressed
  if (e.type == 'keydown') {
    keys[e.key] = true;
  }
  else {
    keys[e.key] = false;
  }

  // Run on all keys and determine which are pressed
  keysPressed = '';
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(keys)) {
    if (value) {
      keysPressed += key;
    }
  }

  // Show key presses
  document.querySelector('.keys').innerHTML = keysPressed;
}
```

```html
<div class="keys">Press some keys</div>
```